# Replace date part of datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a bunch of `datetime` values where I need to replace the date part with a specific date passed as a parameter (an `nvarchar(8)` formatted as `YYYYMMDD`). The time part should stay same as before.

For instance, I've got this row of `datetime` values:

```
Id | DocDate                 | CreationDate            | PrintDate 
1  | 2012-10-01 00:44:20.150 | 2012-10-07 00:44:20.150 | 2012-10-07 00:50:20.150
```

If I'm passing `'20121005'`, the values should change like this:

```
Id | DocDate                 | CreationDate            | PrintDate
1  | 2012-10-05 00:44:20.150 | 2012-10-05 00:44:20.150 | 2012-10-05 00:50:20.150
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, docdate datetime,
                  creationdate datetime,
                  printdate datetime);
INSERT @t SELECT
 1, '2012-10-01 00:44:20.150',
    '2012-10-07 00:44:20.150',
    '2012-10-07 00:50:20.150';

DECLARE @newdate datetime = '20121005';

UPDATE @T SET
  docdate = dateadd(d,datediff(d,docdate,@newdate),docdate),
  creationdate = dateadd(d,datediff(d,creationdate,@newdate),creationdate),
  printdate = dateadd(d,datediff(d,printdate,@newdate),printdate);

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

The pattern of changing just the date portion of a datetime is to first find the difference (in days) that you need to apply, then apply it.

```
 e.g. datediff(d, '20121001', '20121008') => +7 days
      dateadd(d, <+7>, '20121001 xx:xx') => add the 7 days, keeping time
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be frank, I have no idea if I am answering the question you are looking for an answer to.  Try being a little more verbose next time.  That being said, use dateadd.

```
DECLARE @Date1 datetime,
        @Date2 datetime

set @Date1 = '2012-01-01 16:53:20.150'
set @Date2 = '2012-10-06'

SELECT @Date1 as Original, @Date2 as NewDate, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date1)), @Date1), @Date2) as Updated
```

Produces:

```
Original                NewDate                 Updated
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2012-01-01 16:53:20.150 2012-10-06 00:00:00.000 2012-10-06 16:53:20.150

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Basically, use `DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date1))` to get the date by itself, then get the number of milliseconds into that day by subtracting the total date by the result of the above computation and add them to the new date.

You could also perform this via string manipulation or assumptions based off of the result of a single datediff (`DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, @Date1) % 8600000), @Date2)` comes to mind), but those make me feel queasy.